# What's the point of a protected member in System.Object?

Tags: c#

A protected member is accessible within its class and by derived class instances.

If every type in .NET derives from Object, is there any difference between a protected member and a public member in System.Object?

Comment: It stops you from writing `42.MemberwiseClone()`.  That's good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you said, a protected member is accessible within its class and any inheriting classes. A public member is accessible from any other class.

I see two protected members of `Object` in the MSDN documentation: `Finalize` and `MemberwiseClone`. Those methods are callable within any inheriting classes (i.e. any class), but not publicly accessible. If we have the following:

```
class Foo
{
    object Test()
    {
        return this.MemberwiseClone();  
        // Works, because Foo can see protected MemberwiseClone
        // inherited from Object
    }
}

class Bar
{
    object Test()
    {
        var foo = new Foo();
        return foo.MemberwiseClone();
        // fails: Bar cannot see Foo's protected MemberwiseClone
        // because Bar does not inherit from Foo
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**

Just because you can access your "copy" of the protected member, it doesn't mean you can access another type's "copy". The following code would work with a "public" modifier.

The point in putting a protected member into `Object` (provided you were able to) would be to force all objects to to have that member, without exposing it to each other.

To prove it, I wrote this code (this won't compile):

```
class BaseClass
{
    protected bool sharedMember;
}

class DerivedClassA : BaseClass
{
   public DerivedClassA()
   {
      DerivedClassB otherObject = new DerivedClassB();
      otherObject.sharedMember = sharedMember; //Compiler error, cannot access protected member
   }
}

class DerivedClassB : BaseClass
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There is a difference!

For example, say you wanted every object in your application to store its time of creation. You want all inheritors of Object to be able to read their OWN time of creation, but you DON'T want other objects to be able to read the time of creation of their peers.

You can provide this encapsulation with *protected*.

Every sub-class, no matter how far down the chain, will be able to access its time of creation by the expression: this.timeOfCreation. *Other objects will be unable* to access, someOtherObject.timeOfcreation.

But, **if you make timeOfCreation *public*, then ALL objects will be able to read** the time of creation of other objects simply through the expression: someOtherObject.timeOfCreation. Now time of creation is not encapsulated/hidden at all!

So ***protected*** is always useful if you want to keep information ***secret to the instance*** of a class and all of its children. *Public is useful if you don't care who* can see the information inside of a class. (e.g. if you don't desire any data privacy)